# What happens to the chosen vice president if a party's presidential candidate were to die before election day?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, parties

I would like to know if the person chosen to be vice president automatically becomes the party's presidential candidate if the party's presidential candidate were to die before election day.

So, let's say that Joe Biden is the Democratic Party's presidential candidate and he has chosen Hillary Clinton to be his VP. If Joe Biden were to die a few days before election day, will Hillary Clinton automatically be the presidential candidate and would she be free to chose her VP before or after election day?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12582/what-happens-if-donald-trump-or-hillary-clinton-drop-out-of-the-2016-american-pr?rq=1

Comment: @yoozer8, I read over the answers given in that related post, however, would this mean that either the DNC or RNC leadership would get to decide who their candidate would be without having to hold new primaries in all 50 states? In other words, could this decision be made by one person, such as the chairperson of the DNC/RNC?

Comment: What that doesn't address is the ability to get onto the ballet across the country.