What happens if a leading Presidential candidate dies with no running mate?
As everyone's probably aware of by now, there was a failed assassination attempt on Donald Trump yesterday.  Trump is the presumptive Republican nominee for President, with an overwhelming lead in delegate count and no opponents actively campaigning against him for the position.  However, the convention has not been held yet, and he has not selected a running mate as his VP pick. (Or at least, if he has, it has not been publicly announced.)
Under those circumstances, what would have happened to his campaign, and the Republican nomination process in general, had he been killed?

Highly related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12582/12027

The candidate having a running mate is nearly irrelevant - parties do not have the same concept of succession as governments must.

@user121330 True, but at the same time, it would at least leave the running mate in a state of "presumed heir" and give them some degree of advantage when it comes to assigning delegates, particularly if the campaign officially announced "this is now [running mate]'s campaign for President."

Both candidates seem at about equal chance of dying, though of different causes...

They would select a presidential nominee at the convention. The delegates bound to Trump would no longer be bound, and can vote for whomever they decide if there was no clear indication of someone Trump wanted to be presidential nominee instead. The nominee so selected by the convention would select a running mate, which would be ratified by the convention. Or the convention can change the process altogether if they wanted, given the unprecedented situation.
Whether the presumptive nominee had selected a running mate or not doesn't change this -- the delegates bound to a candidate do not automatically get bound to a running mate if the candidate dies.

Not entirely unprecedented.  In 1968, RFK was assassinated after winning enough delegates to influence (but not win) the nomination.  The leading candidate for the People's Party nomination in 1892 died (of natural causes) shortly before the convention.  There have been other non-competitive parties where the leading candidate died before (or even during) the convention.

@Mark What leading candidate died during the convention?  Unfortunately recent events overwhelming search results have made it extremely difficult to find the answer.

@Yakk I'm interested in reading about the specifics of how the actual convention proceeded in this incredibly unusual case.

@Chuu, I remembered incorrectly.  It was a week after the convention that the 1928 Socialist Labor Party candidate drowned while trying to rescue a boy from a river.
